# Article content navigator in wordpress like mbaskool website

Tags: plugins, posts, plugin-wp-pagenavi

Is there any way to allow navigation in an article within same post in Wordpress. or any such plugins ? Because i searched a lot, but could not find a way.

For example : Check this link http://www.mbaskool.com/fun-corner/top-brand-lists/3457-top-10-automobile-brands-of-the-world-2012.html?start=6

where we can navigate through top 10 items of same post

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `nextpage` tag in the post (`alt+shift+p` shortcut in editor).

```
<!--nextpage-->
```

If the pagination doesn't show there anyway, you have to add `wp_link_pages` function to the single file template.

```
wp_link_pages();
```